# How to Get 4lat & Long corner points of any country using maps

Tags: ios, google-maps, maps, apple-maps

I would like to get 4 Lat & Long values of any country, for Suppose let me take India, for India I need east, west, North & south Coordinates, So as i can calculate those 4 points to get a centre point to zoom

or

Please suggest me any idea, How to zoom country wise, if name given I need to that particular country

Answer (score 0):

Find the country in [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org) using the search facility in the top-left, then press 'Export'. Now press 'Manually select a different area', then drag out a rectangle to enclose the country. You will see the four extremes of latitude and longitude displayed in the top-left of the screen.